# Find $\lim_{n \to \infty}f_n(x)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, limits, polynomials

Find $$\lim_{n \to \infty}f_n(x)$$ where $$f_n(x)=n^2x(1-x)^n$$ $0 \lt x \lt 1$

My try:

By symmetry $$\lim_{n \to \infty}f_n(x)=\lim_{n \to \infty}f_n(1-x)=\lim_{n \to \infty}n^2(1-x)x^n=(1-x)\lim_{n \to \infty}n^2 x^n$$

Now $$\lim_{n \to \infty}n^2 x^n=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{x^n}{\frac{1}{n^2}}$$

Now can we use L'hopital's rule here?

Comment: You can skip the intermediate step and simply write $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(1-x)^n}{n^{-2}}$$ from the beginning. Otherwise, yes, this is correct and you can apply l'Hospital's rule, here (although, in this form, it won't be helpful). Flip the fraction, and you'll get something more helpful: $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^2}{(1-x)^{-n}}.$$ Now the numerator will become a constant after two applications of l'Hospital's rule.

Comment: L'Hopital's rule is valid for limits at infinity so yes this is fine

Comment: What symmetry? Only $f_1$ is symmetric in the $x \leftrightarrow 1-x$ interchange.

Answer (score 2):

It might be easier to use the [Ratio Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test):
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{f_{n+1}(x)}{f_n(x)}
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(n+1)^2}{n^2}(1-x)\\
&=1-x
\end{align}
$$
For $0\lt x\lt1$, we have $0\lt1-x\lt1$. Therefore, the series
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty f_n(x)
$$
converges. Thus, the terms go to zero. That is,
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)=0
$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Use L'hopital rule to find $\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x)$, where
$$f_n(x) = x  \frac{n^2}{(1-x)^{-n}}.$$

Answer (score 1):

An option:

For $0< x <1$,  show that

$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} n^2x^n =0.$

Set $x=e^{-y} , y>0$, and consider $\dfrac{n^2}{e^{ny}}$.

$e^{ny} =$

$ 1+ ny +(ny)^2/2! + (ny)^3/3! +.. \gt (ny)^3/3!$.

Hence :

$\dfrac{n^2}{e^{ny}} \lt \dfrac{(3!)n^2}{n^3y^3}= (\dfrac{3!}{y^3})(\dfrac{1}{n}).$

The limit $n \rightarrow \infty$ is?

Answer (score 1):

Denote $y=\dfrac{1}{x}$. Since $0<x<1$,then $y>1.$ Hence
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}n^2 x^n=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{n^2}{y^n}=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{2n}{y^n\ln y}=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{2}{y^n(\ln y)^2}=0.$$

Answer (score -1):

Differentiate to find the max.
If it goes to zero,
that's the limit;
otherwise the limit 
depends on $x$.

If
$f_n(x)=n^2x(1-x)^n$,
then

$\begin{array}\\
f_n'(x)
&=n^2(x(1-x)^n)'\\
&=n^2((1-x)^n-nx(1-x)^{n-1})\\
&=n^2(1-x)^{n-1}((1-x)-nx)\\
&=n^2(1-x)^{n-1}(1-(n+1)x)\\
&=0
\qquad\text{for } x=1/(n+1)
\end{array}
$

At $x=1/(n+1)$,

$\begin{array}\\
f_n(x)
&=n^2(1/(n+1))(1-1/(n+1))^n\\
&=n^2(1/(n+1))(n/(n+1))^n\\
&=n\dfrac1{(1+1/n)(1+1/n)^n}\\
&\approx n\dfrac1{e}\\
&\to \infty\\
\end{array}
$

So
$\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(0)$
does not exist
since
$f_n(0) = 0$.

If
$f_n(x)
=x(1-x)^n$
then
$\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x) = 0$
for $0 \le x \le 1$.

Comment: This doesn't seem right. You've correctly shown that the convergence is nonuniform, but that wasn't asked for. A function can converge pointwise without converging uniformly, and in this case $\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x) = 0$ for all $x \in (0,1)$.